# PDF is display as mirror reflected PDF in "zanysoft/laravel-pdf" package in laravel for generate PDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.4

I am using "zanysoft/laravel-pdf" package in laravel to generate PDF and I am succeed to generate PDF but that PDF is display as mirror reflected PDF. How can i solve this issue ?

[image: i want in left Marked part that is S.N and then Question and then Explanantion etc.]

i want in left Marked part that is S.N and then Question and then Explanantion etc.

Comment: Can you show your code for generating this PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the order of Table  and  means serial no should be at the last and last column should be first. and some extra CSS code for alignment.

**Here is code example**

```
<table class="table  table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr >
                                <td <strong>Subject</strong></td>
                                <td <strong>Teacher</strong></td>
                                <td <strong>Explanation</strong></td>
                                <td <strong>Question</strong></td>
                                <td <strong>S.N</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```